# Invalid Date when trying to sort by date on datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, momentjs

Hello everyone im trying to sort a data-table by dates i've tried to use moment js however doesn't seem to work at all.

[image]

I keep getting the "invalid date" message on the date row.

The information for the data-table comes from the server, and i receive it like this:

```
returnedData["ingresos"].forEach(function(ingreso){
                    $("#Parte-data").append("<tr><td><center>" + ingreso["fecha_ingreso"] + "</center></td><td><center>" + ingreso["codigo"] + "</center></td><td><center> -- </center></td><td><center>" + ingreso["orden_ingreso"] + "</center></td><td><center> -- </center></td><td><center>" + ingreso["balance"] + "</center></td><td><center>" + ingreso["cantidad_ingresada"] + "</center></td><td><center> -- </center></td><td><center>" + ingreso["usuario"]["nombre"] + "</center></td></tr>");
                });
                
                returnedData["salidas"].forEach(function(salida){
                    
                    $("#Parte-data").append("<tr><td><center>" + salida["fecha_salida"] + "</center></td><td><center>" + salida["codigo"] + "</center></td><td><center>" + salida["contrato"] + "</center></td><td><center>" + tg + "</center></td><td><center>" + salida["cantidad_salida"] + "</center></td><td><center>" + salida["balance"] + "</center></td><td><center> -- </center></td><td><center>" + salida["tecnico"]["nombre"] + "</center></td><td><center>" + salida["usuario"]["nombre"] + "</center></td></tr>");
                });
```

The information comes from "ingresos" and from "salidas", and in the data-table i tried this:

```
table = $('#Data-parte').DataTable({
                ordering: false,
                pageLength: 25,
                responsive: true,
                dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
                
                columnDefs:[{
                    targets: 0,
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('DD-MM-YYYY', 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
                }],
            });
```

The format of the dates i get from the server is dd-mm-yyyy.

Here is the data I get from the server:

[image]

Fields used in the dataTable are "fecha_ingreso" from "ingresos" and "fecha_salida" from "salidas".

I don't understand what is missing, hope somebody can help me with this please :(

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the raw data you are getting from the server?

Comment: Also, is the moment function operating on the raw date string or on your updated string (where the data is embedded in some HTML)? `<tr><td><center>26-08-2020</center></td><td><center>` - thanks for clarifications.

Comment: i added the data from the server

Comment: The table is called after the "ingresos" and "salidas" are called so yea it is operating on the updated when everything is added

Comment: OK - so that's not a valid date  It's a date embedded in HTML. You can pass the raw date to DataTables and then use a DataTables `columnDefs.render` function to build the display value - and also a separate [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) value for sensible sorting (with help from moment.js). For example, the sort value could be YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: I placed the table before the returneddata parts and the message stopped, however its not sorting correctly still :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using some standard test data, just to illustrate the approach I was referring to in my comments.

The dates are displayed in the table in your format of DD-MM-YYYY, but they use an orthogonal format (YYYYMMDD) for sorting, which is hidden, behind the scenes.

The example also uses a render function to wrap your data in the HTML you want to use.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>03-08-2020</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>14-06-2020</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>25-12-2019</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {
      columnDefs:[{
        targets: 4,
        render: function ( data, type, row ) {
          //console.log(data); // the raw date as a string
          var d = moment(data, 'DD-MM-YYYY'); // converted to a moment object
          var sortString = moment(d).format('YYYYMMDD'); // converted to a new string format
          //console.log(sortString);
          var cellContents = '<center>' + data + '</center>';
          if ( type === 'display' || type === 'filter' ) {
            return cellContents;
          } else {
            return sortString;
          }
        }
      }]
    } );

} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The table looks like this:

[image]

Note how the date column is sorted chronologically (oldest to newest) using your display format.

The key points to note are:

1. The render function is for column index 4 in my case  (the 5th displayed column).
2. The column is centered in the cell because of the extra HTML I added.
3. The render function provides 2 orthogonal values: (a) the display value (html and date string), and also (b) a second date format for sorting (yyyymmdd).
4. For the `type === 'display' || type === 'filter'` line, these are two of the orthogonal data values I mentioned - [see more information here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#Computed-values). By default the sort date is used for the `sort` orthogonal type: `else { return sortString; }`

Comment: i appreciate the effort a lot, however i tested your solution and sorting still wrong :( keeps showing first the "ingresos" then "salidas" instead of ordering them by the date

Comment: @Juan94 - Can you edit your question to show the latest version of your code, and to show the problem you are having? (Also, if possible, can you show the problem using a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?)